# how can i push into an array a selected radio and some how delete the unselected one in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what i want to know is how can i put a checked / un checked radio so i know to push or delete it from the database that in the summary will sum a price (the price will sum with which radio was selected and delete from index the one that was un selected) can someone help me make it right? thanks.

```
$(".all_radios").click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    arr.push($(this).data('ele_id')); //if radio checked push into      
    console.log("radio = true " + arr);
  }
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    arr.splice($.inArray($(this).data('ele_id'), arr), 1); //if   radio unchecked delete the (this)index            
    console.log("radio = false " + arr);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
$(".all_radios").click(function() {
  arr = [];
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    arr.push($(this).data('ele_id')); //if radio checked push into  
    console.log("radio = true " + arr);
  }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xaLxkhzx/1/)

Comment: hi , thanks for the comment , this is nice answer if i have only few radios , i have like 30-35 radios that goes in foreach in the html and all goes to the database and what i check is what was checked will sum a price (every radio has own price) and in php it sums and in last page it shows the price.

Comment: Different sets of radio button? That is what you meant right?

Comment: It will be great if you provide sample html also

Comment: Radio button or checkbox?

Comment: @leodov PHP wont work in fiddle. Please copy paste the HTML. :)

Comment: $pages = q( "SELECT * FROM Pages" );
<? $elements = q( "SELECT * FROM ElementPages WHERE PageId=?",         $page['ID'] );
    $counter=0;
    foreach ( $elements as $element )
    { ?>

Comment: <?if($element['ElementType']=='radio')
      {?>
    <div class="col-md-3 buttons">
      <input <? if($counter++==0) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> data-ele_id="
      <? echo $element['ID'];?>" data-page_name="
        <?echo $page['PageName'];?>" data-nextpage="page_
          <? echo $element['ElementUse'];?>" data-radio_name="
            <? echo $element['Name']; ?>" name="
              <?echo $element['Name'];?>" id="
                <? echo $element['ElementName'];?>" class="rad btn btn-default

Comment: <? echo $element['ElementType']=='radio' ? "all_radios" : "" ?>" type="
                    <? echo $element['ElementType'];?>" value="
                      <? echo $element['ElementText']; ?>" />
                        <? echo $element['ElementType']=='radio' ? $element['ElementText'] : "" ?>
    </div>
    <?}?>
      <?}?>

Comment: sorry i don't know how to paste html without fiddle ... i'm kinda new :/ (my friend helped me with a code ) but if u have suggestions put them maybe it will be better code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code helps you .
This is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/n48rrtxq/

```
$( "input:radio" ).click(function()
{       var arr = [];
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            //if radio checked push into    
    arr.push($(this).val());            
            console.log("radio = true "+arr);
            $(this).remove();
        }
        else
        {
            arr.splice( $.inArray($(this).val(), arr), 1 );//if   radio unchecked delete the (this)index            
            console.log("radio = false "+arr);          
        }   
});
```

Comment: according to your code there is no use for that else condition.

Comment: i check this one , it worked - but , it if i always check the same radio it push again and again and the price is always increase , i need something that if it clicked only once i cant click again (means the value gets only ones), thanks.

Comment: @leodov ..  ok i update my answer ... in if statement i add $(this).remove(); .. when you select a radio button its removed .. and not select again

Comment: maybe i didn't explain it more clearly , what i asking is how i push a radio value only once and i i push other radio it will delete it from database than push the other radio that was checked and so on...thanks.